# Oracle Report stuck in post processing when trying to generate a report

Tags: oracle-ebs, oracle-xml-publisher

I am creating a Oracle Report. The report is supposed to take a bunch of input and create the report. It is not working for some specific cases.

The input are as follows
1. Account number
2.org id
3. start _date
4.end date

the report is supposed to generate a report for the org_id(constant) based on the account number and for date between start date and end date.

When the account_number is not provided it will return all the information regarding all accounts.

It works when I give specific account information
It works for specific dates (10-jan-25th jan ,20thjan-31st-jan) with out any account number: i.e. it returns information about all account number for given time period.

but it fails to give me information about 10-jan-31st jan. Which I can not figure out why.

I have tried to get the xml and put it in the template and create a preview, 
the preview does not work and gives me the following error:

error: Conf File: C:\Template Builder for Word\config\xdo config.xml Font Dir: C:\Template Builder for Word\fonts Run XDO Start Template: C:\MyFiles\XML_Publisher\lATEST OUTPUT\XXONT_M193_CANCELLED_HOLDS .rtf RTFProcessor setLocale: en-us FOProcessor setData: C:\MyFiles\XML_Publisher\Test\errchk15jan7feb.xml FOProcessor setLocale: en-us

Answer (score 0):

With the longer date range, the XML file might be too big for the output postprocessor. Did you check the size of the XML file?
If this is the problem, you can use our company's Blitz Report, which doesn't have size limitations: https://www.enginatics.com/faq/#how-does-blitz-report-compare-with-oracle-bi-publisher